# How do we extend trackpad touch area all the way to the edge in OS X?

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch

For example, when touching on the very edges of the trackpad, OS X ignores gestures. In Linux, I can use the full trackpad.

How do I use the full trackpad in OS X? How do I tell OS X not to ignore the edges of the trackpad?

EDIT: oops, looks like I posted a duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233928/how-to-enable-touch-on-the-bottom-edge-of-the-trackpad, but no responses there yet. :(

Comment: You can't. This is just a system software thing, and unfortunately, you can't go in and modify system software. There's no setting for it and I don't imagine there's a third-party app for this.

Comment: @JohnRamos Add as answer please :)

Comment: @JMY1000 Not really sure why that "sorry we can't help" should be an answer, but I added it like you said ;).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't. This is just a system software thing, and unfortunately, you can't go in and modify system software. There's no setting for it and I don't imagine there's a third-party app for this.